# Tkinter UI freezes when button is pressed

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-multithreading, freeze

Hi when i press the start button the thread starts and another cancel button to stop it.

```
def button_callback(self):
    self.stop_threads.clear()
    self.beep_th = threading.Thread(target=self.process, daemon=True)
    self.beep_th.start()

def terminate(self):
    self.stop_threads.set()
    self.beep_th.join()
    self.beep_th = None
```

This is all in my top window

In the process i am calling a function from another class by using file.Inpdir and outdir are input and output destinations

```
def process(self):
    while not self.stop_threads.is_set():
        time.sleep(0.5)
        global file
        file = Extract(inpdir, outdir)
        self.c = file.read()
        self.progress['value'] = 20
        self.lbl4.destroy()
        self.lbl4 = Label(self.top, text='Progress 20%', background='#080E1E', fg='White')
        self.lbl4.place(x=100, y=300)
        self.top.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.a = file.start
        self.progress['value'] = 60
        self.lbl4.destroy()
        self.lbl4 = Label(self.top, text='Progress 60%', background='#080E1E', fg='White')
        self.lbl4.place(x=100, y=300)
        self.top.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(1)
        file.document()
        self.progress['value'] = 80
        self.lbl4.destroy()
        self.lbl4 = Label(self.top, text='Progress 80%', background='#080E1E', fg='White')
        self.lbl4.place(x=100, y=300)
        self.top.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(1)
        file.create()
        self.progress['value'] = 100
        self.lbl4.destroy()
        self.lbl4 = Label(self.top, text='Completed', background='#080E1E', fg='White')
        self.lbl4.place(x=100, y=300)
        self.top.update_idletasks()
```

When i press cancel button to start terminate function it freezes the gui and becomes unresponsive. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: You are using the `time` module, `tkinter` and `time` dont really go well together. Try using `.after()` try this [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/), as it may help

Comment: Tkinter is not multithreading.  Your program can have multiple threads, but all the interactions with tkinter objects should be done in the main thread.  The tkinter .after function is threadsafe, however, and the resulting callback executes in the main thread.  This allows you to communicate events from secondary threads back to the main thread.

Comment: @Dodu where do i add after and in the brackets what do i add

Comment: I dont really use the `.after` method but try the website link i gave. I think this would be the format `toplevelname_or_main_window_name.after(time_period_in_milliseconds_such_as_1000_for_1_second, command)`